# SQL Remove duplicate parent child entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried looking around for this issue and couldn't find much. I was wondering the best method of removing duplicate parent/child rows in an SQL table.

For example I have a table like so:

```
Id | CompanyId | DuplicateId
1  |     1     |     2
2  |     2     |     1    <------ CompanyId 2 is already a duplicate of 1
3  |     2     |     3
```

I wish to select all non duplicates:

```
Id | CompanyId | DuplicateId
1  |     1     |     2
3  |     2     |     3
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be great. Thanks!

Edit: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Oops sorry, Microsoft SQL Server. I'll edit my post with that in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method, that works in most databases:

```
delete from sqltable
     where duplicateid > companyid and
           exists (select 1
                   from sqltable st2
                   where st2.duplicateid = sqltable.companyid and
                         st2.companyid = sqltable.duplicateid
                  );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't even think to use a greater than clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename t1 where CompanyId not IN  (SELECT Duplicateid from  
tablename WHERE CompnayId<>t1.CompanyId and duplicateid > companyid)
```

Comment: Like stated to Gordon, this is exactly the thing I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way in Sql Server to remove dups parent child could be this:

```
  delete from your_table where concat(companyid,duplicateid)in
(
SELECT concat(table1.companyid , table1.duplicateid )
FROM your_table table1
    inner join your_table table2
    ON table1.companyid = table2.duplicateid
    AND table1.duplicateid = table2.companyid and  table1.companyid>table1.duplicateid
)
```

Hope it helps.